# Getting previous exit code of an application on Windows

Tags: windows, exit-code

Is there any way to find out what was the last Exit Code of an application the last time it run?

I want to check if application wasn't exit with zero exit code last time (which means abnormal termination in my case) And if so, do some checking and maybe fix/clean up previously generated data.

Since some applications do this (they give a warning and ask if you want to run in Safe Mode this time) I think maybe Windows can tell me this.

And if not, what is the best practice of doing this? Setting a flag on a file or something when application terminated correctly and check that next time it executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no permanent record of the exit code.  It exists only as long as a handle to the process is kept open.  And returned by GetExitCodeProcess(), it needs that handle.  As soon as the last handle is closed then that exit code is gone for good.  One technique is a little bootstrapper app that starts the process and keeps the handle.  It can then also do other handy things like send alerts, keep a log, clean up partial files or record minidumps of crashes.  Use WaitForSingleObject() to detect the process exit.

Btw, you definitely want to exit code number to mean the opposite thing.  A zero is always the "normal exit" value.  This helps you detect hard crashes.  The exit code is always non-zero when Windows terminates the app forcibly, set to the exception code.

There are other ways, you can indeed create a file or registry key that indicates the process is running and check for that when it starts back up.  The only real complication with it is that you need to do something meaningful when the user starts the program twice.  Which is a hard problem to solve, such apps are usually single-instance apps.  You use a named mutex to detect that an instance of the program is already running.  Imprinting the evidence with the process ID and start time is workable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard way to do this on the Windows Platform.

The easiest way to handle this case is to put a value on the registry and to clear it when the program exits.

If the value is still present when the program starts, then it terminated unexpectedly.
Put a value in the HKCU/Software// to be sure you have sufficient rights (the value will be per user in this case).